# Oracle Materialized View Not Supporting NVL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, materialized-views

I have created a simple Materialized View in Oracle with this query

```
SELECT p.registration_no, s.sponsor_no, s.sponsor_name, p.resignation_date
FROM nmr_registration_public p, lct_sponsor s
WHERE p.sponsor_no = s.sponsor_no;
```

I have set its refresh mode as `FORCE ON COMMIT` and it is working properly.

I have altered the query like this by just adding `NVL(p.resignation_date, SYSDATE)` statement like this

```
SELECT p.registration_no, s.sponsor_no, s.sponsor_name, NVL(p.resignation_date, SYSDATE)
FROM nmr_registration_public p, lct_sponsor s
WHERE p.sponsor_no = s.sponsor_no;
```

Then I am getting this error

**ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view**

Is `NVL` not supported in MViews if the refresh mode is set as `ON COMMIT`?
And are there any other statements that do not support `ON COMMIT`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `nvl` but in `sysdate`

> The defining query of the materialized view cannot contain any
>   non-repeatable expressions (ROWNUM, SYSDATE, non-repeatable PL/SQL
>   functions, and so on).

Comment: Will it support nested queries?